# How to pass values from a subclass of UIView to UIViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a class `Graph` that subclasses `UIView`.

I am in my view controller class and I call the `SliderView` class with the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        SliderView = [[SliderView alloc] init];
    }

    [self setView: SliderView];
}
```

I'd like to be able to access to the properties I have setup in `SliderView` in my view controller class. How can I do this?

Comment: First of all Variable Shoudn't begin by a maj =/

Comment: Can't you just call the getters and setters?

Comment: have you got an example of how to do this?

Comment: `[graph propertyName]` and `[graph setPropertyName:newValue]`

Comment: You are not following proper naming conventions. `Graph` is a class, and can't be set to a value. You cannot set the `view` property of a view controller in its `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Graph needs to be a pointer `Graph *graph = [[Graph alloc] init];`

Comment: Sorry guys, Graph was just placeholder text. I've updated my question;

Comment: It looks like calling the getters and setters do work. Thanks @cabellicar123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getters and setters like Kyle said (he just went further showing the property).

`[graph propertyName]` and `[graph setPropertyName:newValue]`

I would also take a look at: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to access the properties of the Graph class. In your Graph class you might have some thing along the lines of:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *propertyName;
```

You would access it in the UIViewController by way of something like

```
[(Graph *)self.view propertyName];
```

Comment: NSObject should be replaced with whatever class the property is. "propertyName" is arbitrary and you can name it anything you like.

Comment: Thanks Kyle but this does not work. Error: Expected Expression